# Error using propel, it can't find build-propel.xml

Tags: php, propel

When trying to create a build using propel-gen (propel v 1.4) I get:

> [phing] Error reading project file
>   [wrapped: Unable to open
>   /path/to/project/build-propel.xml for
>   reading: ]

I can't find a reference to this file in the propel documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that it was looking for files which are located in the propel/generator directory, but was using the current working directory as the base directory (I have propel-gen symlinked to /usr/bin so I can run it from anywhere).

The (kind of crappy) solution is just to cd into the propel/generator directory and run the build from there, so it uses that directory as the base path.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a problem with the latest phing.

You should try :

```
$ pear uninstall -n phing/phing
$ pear install phing/phing-2.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of [Phing](http://phing.info/) are your using? (Run `phing -v` to find out). Phing 2.4.x, the latest version, [seems to break backwards compatibility](http://groups.google.com/group/propel-development/browse_thread/thread/4b89128f4e7ec04d/613ce3869fead6e1?lnk=gst), but it works with Phing 2.3.x, so try to [downgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569012/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-phpunit-through-pear) to that version for now.