# how to revert back to older vs of symfony?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a project directory:

`~/traffic_2/phoenix$` the symfony version here is 1.4.11 because I tried to install symfony in ANOTHER project directory using the command:

```
~/traffic_2/elemental/webroot$ sudo pear install symfony/symfony
```

so it updated to version 1.4.11 in directory `~/traffic_2/phoenix`!

I want to revert back to my previous version of symfony 1.4.2 please in above dir???

please how do I do this??
`~/traffic_2/phoenix$sudo pear install symfony/symfony-1.4.2` ?????
thank you

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling the previous package, it should be ok. Look here : [How to install an older version of PHPUnit through PEAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569012/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-phpunit-through-pear)

Comment: pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUNit
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.3.17

so i will in my case then have:
pear uninstall symfony/symfony1.4.11
pear install symfony/symfony1.4.2??

sorry for the stupid q's but cannot afford to make a mistake and im still learning symfony :)

Comment: `pear uninstall symfony/symfony` should be sufficient for the first command. BTW, how come you can't afford to make a mistake? Are you on a production machine with several symfony projects on it, and different versions?

Comment: no i am on my devbox and have severeal projects all on version 1.4.2 and dont know anything about the new version, just want the old version back please..i am new here and have nobody that can help or give advise :)

Comment: Ok, because I'm working here with several versions of symfony. I didn't use pear at all, I just downloaded all the version I needed in a directory, and for each project, lib/vendor/symfony is nothing but a symbolic link pointing to one of this folder. This way, I can switch quite easily. But still, I don't understand why you want to go back to 1.4.2 , 1.4.11 is still 1.4 , which means the changes between the two versions are only security improvements. So you don't really need to "know anything" more about the "new" version. Just keep it and you'll be fine!

Comment: thank you it worked..i am back to 1.4.2 but now i have another project directory ans tried to install symfony there and got this:


helloises@helloise:~/traffic_2/elemental/webroot$ sudo pear install symfony/symfony-1.4.2
symfony/symfony is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.4.2
install failed

what am i doing wrong please?
thank you

Comment: I think pear install <packagename> installs the package globally, somewhere it can be used with php (in a directory listed in your include_path php setting). I think it must be something like /usr/share/php/

Comment: yes quite right it is installed globally and yes it is in usr/share/php/symfony  but i need to run symfony commands from dir: helloises@helloise:~/traffic_2/elemental/webroot$

and want to follow what they state on the official symfony website: 

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony
shall i follow their steps they give there under "Installing from an archive"?

thank you

Comment: Normally, the symfony commands should be run from `~/traffic_2/elemental` (the project root, not the document root). The package comes with an executable file in it, probably located somewhere under `/usr/share/php/symfony/` , which you can use for the next steps in the tutorial. I don't know why the pear installation isn't documented anymore. If you are starting a new project, you should probably use the subversion method, and the archive version in production. This way you could use 1.4.11 without affecting your other projects.

Comment: yikes im confused... in the elemental directory there is only the webroot directory, nothing else...can you please just step by step give me the commands i must execute??? sorry about this.. i have a /usr/share/php/symfony dir but what do i do with it? how must i use it??

thank you

Comment: Is elemental a brand new project or a project which used sf 1.4.2 and is broken because of the changes you made? If is new, why is there a webroot directory in it? If it isn't why is there *only* a webroot directory in it?

Comment: it is brand new...in the elemental directory there is ONLY a webroot directory and in the webroot all the .php files  i got this structure and code from a company as is and need to use it as it is structured..i am maintaining this code now...

Comment: If you got it from a company, then it is not brand new at all. But it must be a symfony project anyway, what does the webroot directory contain `ls ~/traffic_2/elemental/webroot` ?