# Installing PHPUnit w/ XAMPP on Mac OS X

Tags: php, apache, phpunit, xampp, pear

Does anyone know how to install PHPUnit on Mac OS X (I'm using XAMPP). I tried the following commands and it said installation succeeded (no errors). Now, when I try to run a phpunit command in Terminal, I get an error that the command phpunit could not be found. Also, running "which phpunit" returns nothing.

The commands I ran:

```
    $sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
    $sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
    $sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pear channel-discover components.ez.no
    $sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pear install -a phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hung? Internet working? Little Snitch or something else blocking connection? All that looks fine.

Comment: Got it to go through (Internet was having issues). It said installation was successful but I can't run the phpunit commands (it says the hpunit command is not found. Also, running "which phpunit" returns nothing.

Comment: phpunit isn't added to your paths, so the OS doesn't know it exists. Try navigating to the folder where PHPUnit is installed and run `phpunit` from there?

Answer (score 1):

Installing PHPunit through XAMPP almost drove me mad, an error was telling me that my xdebug version was to old to install the Coverage lib required for PHPunit, three seconds later another was telling me that everything was fine but no phpunit command was installed.

I've chosen to bypass that problem by installing phpunit at system level (outside of XAMPP).

```
cd /tmp
curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.phar
sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

This should install pear (and tell you where, default is in your home).

```
cd ~/pear/bin
sudo ./pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo ./pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo ./pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo ./pear install -a phpunit/PHPUnit
```

./phpunit should now return you something (in my case it's displaying that some import where unmet.

```
Warning: require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ~/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 45

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in ~/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 45
```

If you don't have a /etc/php.ini, create it:

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Then edit /etc/php.ini and set the right path:

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/Users/YOURUSERNAME/pear/share/pear"
```

Then calling ./phpunit in your pear bin directory should work... It's quite a pain comparing to a few aptitude and pear call on Ubuntu, but it let you work on OSX. You should be able to still use XAMPP as a webserver but remember that XAMPP uses its buildin PHP environment, phpunit will use the one of your system.

Answer (score 1):

AsTeR's method worked for me though because being stuck with old **PHP 5.3.1** current PHPUnit versions will complain because function **stream_resolve_include_path** is missing.

So I ended up used the solution together with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249291

Answer (score 0):

I did as @trent-scott did and got same error.

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:')
```

As you can notice there is an empty include path (include_path='.:')..

Go to your php.ini file. Figure out which by doing this in terminal 'php --ini'.

Make sure you've got something similar to this somewhere in the file (be sure to replace username):

```
include_path=".:/Users/hfossli/pear/share/pear"
```

It should be sufficient, but I for some reason got this (be sure to replace username):

```
include_path=".:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear:/Users/hfossli/pear/share/pear"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fund an other temporary solution that worked for me. Instead of using the pear command directly within your Xampp app, try using the full path to pear executable like : /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pear

hope it helped.