# installing phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.5 via pear (for sonar)

Tags: php, maven, phpunit, pear, sonarqube

I am trying to setup [PHP Plugin for Sonar](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin), and this plugin needs specific packages in specific version.

So, When I am trying to install PHPUnit 3.5.5 using following command, it is installing newer version. What I do wrong?

```
[VMWARE] root@localhost ~  
 # pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.5
Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "soap"
phpunit/DbUnit requires package "phpunit/PHPUnit" (version >= 3.6.0), downloaded version is 3.5.5
phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "phpunit/DbUnit" (version >= 1.0.0)
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1.0)
downloading PHPUnit_Selenium-1.2.1.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_Selenium-1.2.1.tgz (23,083 bytes)
.......done: 23,083 bytes
downloading PHPUnit-3.6.10.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.6.10.tgz (118,595 bytes)
...done: 118,595 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.10
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium-1.2.1
[VMWARE] root@localhost ~
```

Comment: `phpunit/DbUnit` needs `"phpunit/PHPUnit" (version >= 3.6.0)`, as you install it, the later version is installed. Uninstall it and tell pear which version of DBUnit to install instead, e.g. the one that works with PHPUnit 3.5.5. But probably the plugin works with PHPUnit 3.6.10 as well so this isn't actually any issue? (check that first)

Comment: no, it seems not to work with 3.6.10.... I will try with your suggestion installing dbunit first

Comment: pear install phpunit/DbUnit-1.0.0 phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.5 phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium-1.0.1

Comment: see the second highest answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569012/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-phpunit-through-pear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this from the unanswered questions page: See [How to install an older version of PHPUnit through PEAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569012/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-phpunit-through-pear) for an exact answer to your problem.