# Dependencies for PHPUnit 3.4.17

Tags: php, phpunit

This is related to another post ([How to install an older version of PHPUnit through PEAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569012/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-phpunit-through-pear)), however in my case I'm actually installing PHPUnit 3.4.17 (this is due to the fact that I'm building an application in an environment that's running PHP 5.1.6).

I can't find anywhere in PHPUnit documentation which states the exact version numbers that the various dependencies need to be. Does anyone have a list somewhere, specifically for version 3.4 of PHPUnit?

The reason I ask is that I want to make sure that I don't run into any problems mid-way through development because one dependency is too new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 3.4 [docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/installation.html):

> PHPUnit 3.4 requires PHP 5.1.4 (or later) but PHP 5.3.3 (or later) is
>   highly recommended.
>
> Xdebug 2.0.5 (or later) is required to collect and process code
>   coverage information but Xdebug 2.1.0 (or later) is highly
>   recommended.

I don't think there's any other requirements.