# phpunit doesn't work in a yii framework project

Tags: php, yii, phpunit

I just stuck all this morning to figure out this, but without luck.

I create a test under tests/unit

```
<?php

  class DbTest extends CTestCase {

    public function testConnection() {
  $this->assertTrue( true );
    }
  }

?>
```

when I run it in the terminal

```
$ cd tests
$ phpunit unit/DbTest.php
```

I get this error:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.8 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Function 'phpunit_autoload' not found (function 'phpunit_autoload' not found or invalid function name)
```

my phpunit version is 3.7.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1563).

You need to [alter the autoloader](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36320-phpunit-not-working-with-yii-ctestcase-phpunit-autoload-not-found/)'s

or

[downgrade PHPUnit to 3.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569012/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-phpunit-through-pear)

Answer (score 2):

Following thing worked well for me. Found googling.
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37294-yii-unit-test-not-working/

Old Code in framework/test/CTestCase.php, Comment it out.

```
   require_once('PHPUnit/Util/Filesystem.php'); // workaround for PHPUnit <= 3.6.11
   require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
   spl_autoload_unregister('phpunit_autoload');
   Yii::registerAutoloader('phpunit_autoload');
```

And change to this

```
require_once('PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php');
require_once('PHPUnit/Util/Filesystem.php'); // workaround for PHPUnit <= 3.6.11
require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
if (in_array('phpunit_autoload', spl_autoload_functions())) { // PHPUnit >= 3.7 'phpunit_alutoload' was obsoleted
spl_autoload_unregister('phpunit_autoload');
Yii::registerAutoloader('phpunit_autoload');
```

}